# Openweathermap API: how to fetch whether history of multiple cities for last 30 days?

Tags: ios, json, weather-api, openweathermap

I am using **openweathermap** API to get whether history for last 30 day.
I am successfully able to fetch weather history of one city at a time by using **"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=London&APPID=9a1782c0d83dde6f33f8d9977khgjdskhe82ef&type=day&cnt=30"** this API call.

But I want to fetch multiple cities weather history such as **London and New York** then how I call this API. I don't want to call same API twice by changing city name.
Please suggest me a convenient way.

Answer (score 0):

there is no other way than calling the openweathermap api multiple times. However, you can build your own server back-end in between (also good idea when you want to cache data) and deliver data of multiple cities at once.